# Chrome inside docker ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: docker, google-chrome, docker-network

We're trying to run chrome inside a docker container.

The **docker run** command after the build is the following:

```
docker run \
 --rm \
 -ti \
 --add-host=example.my_domain.localhost:172.21.0.13 \
 --env="APP_ENV=test" \
 --privileged \
 --volume "$volumeDir:/app" \
 --cap-add SYS_ADMIN \
 --net custom_network \
 built_image_tag bash
```

**172.21.0.13** is an example to indicate the ip of another container in the **same network**.

Once inside the container the host file look something like this:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
::1 localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
172.21.0.13 example.my_domain.localhost
172.21.0.15 7229a8eac11e
```

and as expected running:

```sh
$ wget example.my_domain.localhost
Connecting to example.my_domain.localhost (example.my_domain.localhost)|172.21.0.13|:80... connected.
```

result in a correct connection

running a connection in the browser, however :

```
$ google-chrome http://example.my_domain.localhost
```

result in a **ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED**.

The browser is able to navigate to any other website.

thanks.

**EDIT:**
Please note that both the **wget** and the opening of the browser are launched **inside** the container, as we use chrome headless for test purposes.

Comment: When you say `wget example.my_domain.localhost` do you mean you are executing that command from *inside* the container? or from the same host machine where you are executing Chrome?

Comment: Both wget and chrome are executed insidie the container, we use chrome to run headless testing

Comment: Could you try adding `--disable-web-security` to the Chrome command?

Answer (score 2):

In my case I'm using [spatie/browsershot](https://github.com/spatie/browsershot), but I believe the underlying issues are the same, so I hope my answer is useful.

My `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` error resolved when the following pieces were in place:

#### 1) The docker container *hosting your site* needs a network alias.

This is instead of adding a hosts file entry in the Puppeteer container, which Chrome did not appear to honour in my testing.

```yaml
services:
  my-nginx-container:
    ...
    networks:
      internal:
        aliases:
          # so we can access our sites directly (by their domain) from other containers.
          - my-docker-site.com
```

#### 2) Add the following Puppeteer args

`--disable-web-security'` and `--enable-features=NetworkService`.

I realise the original question was not asking about Browsershot, but for that the args are added like so:

```php
$browsershot = Browsershot::url('https://my-docker-site.com')
    ->setOption('args', ['--disable-web-security', '--enable-features=NetworkService'])
```

Doing so allowed me to run both Browsershot and Puppeteer inside a container, and for Chrome to be able to access sites hosted inside other containers, by referencing their domain name.

Comment: I got the same issue and as an alternative to changing your docker-compose.yml, you can  use ngrok.

Comment: Wow, I hadn't considered ngrok as a solution for production, but they are certainly doing some interesting things lately!

Comment: can you share your docker-compose.yml for sail?

Comment: @SamAxe — not sure if your question was directed at me, but if so, I don't use Sail. Sorry!